# Conditionally changing values by grouping variable in R; condition based on difftime between timestamps in two dataframes

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, difftime

I am trying to correct some erroneous entries in a dataset in a conditional manner. I need to do this by group and the condition is based on the difference between 2 timestamps across 2 different datasets.

Here are some examples of the types of data that I am working with:-

```
df1<-structure(list(UserID = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", 
                               "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "DDD", "DDD", 
                               "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD"), Value = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", 
                                                                      "Group3", "Group3", "Group1", "Group2", "Group4", "Group5", "Group5", 
                                                                      "Group5", "Group5", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                                                                      "Group2"), Time = structure(c(1577840400, 1577844000, 1577847600, 
                                                                                                    1577966400, 1577970000, 1577973600, 1577977200, 1577977200, 1577980800, 
                                                                                                    1577984400, 1577988000, 1577991600, 1578193200, 1578196800, 1578200400, 
                                                                                                    1578204000, 1578207600, 1578211200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                                                                                    ), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")


df2<-structure(list(UserID = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", 
                               "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "DDD", "DDD"), StartTime = structure(c(1577839980, 
                                                                                                  1577840460, 1577843820, 1577966580, 1577970180, 1577973360, 1577975160, 
                                                                                                  1577977920, 1577978940, 1578193200, 1578193920), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                             "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), EndTime = structure(c(1577840460, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1577843820, 1577846640, 1577970180, 1577973360, 1577975160, 1577978580, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1577978940, 1577980680, 1578193920, 1578196620), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Both datasets look like this:-

```
print(df1)
   UserID  Value                Time
1     AAA Group1 2020-01-01 01:00:00
2     AAA Group1 2020-01-01 02:00:00
3     AAA Group2 2020-01-01 03:00:00
4     BBB Group3 2020-01-02 12:00:00
5     BBB Group3 2020-01-02 13:00:00
6     BBB Group1 2020-01-02 14:00:00
7     BBB Group2 2020-01-02 15:00:00
8     CCC Group4 2020-01-02 15:00:00
9     CCC Group5 2020-01-02 16:00:00
10    CCC Group5 2020-01-02 17:00:00
11    CCC Group5 2020-01-02 18:00:00
12    CCC Group5 2020-01-02 19:00:00
13    DDD Group1 2020-01-05 03:00:00
14    DDD Group2 2020-01-05 04:00:00
15    DDD Group2 2020-01-05 05:00:00
16    DDD Group2 2020-01-05 06:00:00
17    DDD Group2 2020-01-05 07:00:00
18    DDD Group2 2020-01-05 08:00:00

 print(df2)
   UserID           StartTime             EndTime
1     AAA 2020-01-01 00:53:00 2020-01-01 01:01:00
2     AAA 2020-01-01 01:01:00 2020-01-01 01:57:00
3     AAA 2020-01-01 01:57:00 2020-01-01 02:44:00
4     BBB 2020-01-02 12:03:00 2020-01-02 13:03:00
5     BBB 2020-01-02 13:03:00 2020-01-02 13:56:00
6     BBB 2020-01-02 13:56:00 2020-01-02 14:26:00
7     BBB 2020-01-02 14:26:00 2020-01-02 15:23:00
8     CCC 2020-01-02 15:12:00 2020-01-02 15:29:00
9     CCC 2020-01-02 15:29:00 2020-01-02 15:58:00
10    DDD 2020-01-05 03:00:00 2020-01-05 03:12:00
11    DDD 2020-01-05 03:12:00 2020-01-05 03:57:00
```

The timestamp column in df1 is rounded up to each hour, whereas there is a starting timestamp and an ending timestamp in df2 (both are granular and rounded to the minute). There are some entries in df1 that are incorrect because they do not appear in df2 at a corresponding time.

For instance, `UserID` CCC last `EndTime` timestamp in df2 is 2020-01-02 15:58:00, but in df1, CCC appears at 2020-01-02 17:00:00, 2020-01-02 18:00:00 & 2020-01-02 19:00:00; similar instance with `UserID` DDD.

**What I want to do**

If a `UserID` has an entry in df1, with a `df1$Time` timestamp that is >=60 minutes than their last `df2$EndTime` timestamp in df2, I want the entry in the `df1$Value` to be changes to "NoGroup".

Here is an illustrative example of the desired outcome:-

```
   UserID   Value                Time
1     AAA  Group1 2020-01-01 01:00:00
2     AAA  Group1 2020-01-01 02:00:00
3     AAA  Group2 2020-01-01 03:00:00
4     BBB  Group3 2020-01-02 12:00:00
5     BBB  Group3 2020-01-02 13:00:00
6     BBB  Group1 2020-01-02 14:00:00
7     BBB  Group2 2020-01-02 15:00:00
8     CCC  Group4 2020-01-02 15:00:00
9     CCC  Group5 2020-01-02 16:00:00
10    CCC NoGroup 2020-01-02 17:00:00
11    CCC NoGroup 2020-01-02 18:00:00
12    CCC NoGroup 2020-01-02 19:00:00
13    DDD  Group1 2020-01-05 03:00:00
14    DDD  Group2 2020-01-05 04:00:00
15    DDD NoGroup 2020-01-05 05:00:00
16    DDD NoGroup 2020-01-05 06:00:00
17    DDD NoGroup 2020-01-05 07:00:00
18    DDD NoGroup 2020-01-05 08:00:00
```

Any pointers are appreciated as always :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% group_by(UserID) %>% filter(EndTime == max(EndTime)), by = "UserID") %>%
  mutate(Value = if_else(Time-EndTime >= 60, "NoGroup", Value)) %>%
  select(-c(4,5))
```

First you `join` the last `EndTimes` of each `UserID` from `df2` into `df1`, next you check if any `Time` is more than 60 minutes past this `EndTime` and change the `Value` accordingly. Lastly you remove the columns that were added during the `join`

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for this, works brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

```r
df1<-structure(list(UserID = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", 
                               "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "DDD", "DDD", 
                               "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD"), Value = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", 
                                                                      "Group3", "Group3", "Group1", "Group2", "Group4", "Group5", "Group5", 
                                                                      "Group5", "Group5", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                                                                      "Group2"), Time = structure(c(1577840400, 1577844000, 1577847600, 
                                                                                                    1577966400, 1577970000, 1577973600, 1577977200, 1577977200, 1577980800, 
                                                                                                    1577984400, 1577988000, 1577991600, 1578193200, 1578196800, 1578200400, 
                                                                                                    1578204000, 1578207600, 1578211200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                                                                                    ), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")


df2<-structure(list(UserID = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", 
                               "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "DDD", "DDD"), StartTime = structure(c(1577839980, 
                                                                                                  1577840460, 1577843820, 1577966580, 1577970180, 1577973360, 1577975160, 
                                                                                                  1577977920, 1577978940, 1578193200, 1578193920), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                             "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), EndTime = structure(c(1577840460, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1577843820, 1577846640, 1577970180, 1577973360, 1577975160, 1577978580, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1577978940, 1577980680, 1578193920, 1578196620), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

no_groups <-
  df1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% as_tibble()) %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(
    last_end = max(EndTime)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    no_group =  all((last_end - Time) <=  minutes(60))
  ) %>%
  distinct(UserID, no_group)
#> Joining, by = "UserID"
no_groups
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   UserID [4]
#>   UserID no_group
#>   <chr>  <lgl>   
#> 1 AAA    FALSE   
#> 2 BBB    FALSE   
#> 3 CCC    TRUE    
#> 4 DDD    TRUE

df1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  left_join(no_groups) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(no_group, "NoGroup", Value)) %>%
  select(-no_group)
#> Joining, by = "UserID"
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>    UserID Value   Time               
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <dttm>             
#>  1 AAA    Group1  2020-01-01 01:00:00
#>  2 AAA    Group1  2020-01-01 02:00:00
#>  3 AAA    Group2  2020-01-01 03:00:00
#>  4 BBB    Group3  2020-01-02 12:00:00
#>  5 BBB    Group3  2020-01-02 13:00:00
#>  6 BBB    Group1  2020-01-02 14:00:00
#>  7 BBB    Group2  2020-01-02 15:00:00
#>  8 CCC    NoGroup 2020-01-02 15:00:00
#>  9 CCC    NoGroup 2020-01-02 16:00:00
#> 10 CCC    NoGroup 2020-01-02 17:00:00
#> 11 CCC    NoGroup 2020-01-02 18:00:00
#> 12 CCC    NoGroup 2020-01-02 19:00:00
#> 13 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 03:00:00
#> 14 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 04:00:00
#> 15 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 05:00:00
#> 16 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 06:00:00
#> 17 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 07:00:00
#> 18 DDD    NoGroup 2020-01-05 08:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>